# How to use QClipboard.dataChanged signal to change the text in clipboard?

Tags: python, pyqt, clipboard

I want to replace all **parenthesis** into **brackets** in my clipboard, so I have such code in following:

```
import sys
from functools import partial

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


def fun(clipboard):
    text=clipboard.text()
    new_tex=text.replace("(","[").replace(")","]")
    clipboard.setText(new_tex)
    print("content:",text)
    print("content:",new_tex)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

clipboard = app.clipboard()
clipboard.dataChanged.connect(partial(fun,clipboard))

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But I note when I use `clipboard.setText` in slot function, it will trigger the signal **twice** or more.... for example I copy text `bb(1,2,3)`, then this is my output:

> ```
> content: bb(1,2,3)
> content: bb[1,2,3]
> content: 
> content:
> ```

And it will clear all my clipboard, but actually I just want to use `bb[1,2,3]` to replace the original `bb(1,2,3)` in clipboard,  How to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clipboard.setText` trigger the signal `QClipboard::dataChanged()`.

You either need to remove the `clipboard.setText`, or do this:

```
import sys
from functools import partial
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


def fun(clipboard):
    if not clipboard.text():                            # +
        return                                          # +

    text = clipboard.text()
    new_tex = text.replace("(","[").replace(")","]")
    clipboard.setText(new_tex)                          # <---
    print("content: 1 ", text)
    print("content: 2 ", new_tex)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

clipboard = app.clipboard()
clipboard.dataChanged.connect(partial(fun, clipboard))

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Note that this might cause infinite recursion. I suggest you to add a return if `text` and `new_text` are the same, and also `clipboard.blockSignals(True)` before `clipboard.setText` and `clipboard.blockSignals(False)` right after it.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks for your comment. It is very useful to me.

Answer (score -1):

I use a signal to connect the method in which calls `setText()`, and emit the signal with text on data changed in a separate thread.This works for me.

Comment: Could you show your code?