# Detect when a specific URL is copied to the clipboard

Tags: python, clipboard

How can I detect when the text copied to the clipboard has certain text? I need to run a script whenever I copy a specific URL to the clipboard.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: this may be related [How to catch the clipboard event (onChangeClipboard equivalent) from any application in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25900770/how-to-catch-the-clipboard-event-onchangeclipboard-equivalent-from-any-applica)

Answer (score 1):

Using PyQT5 you can register an event handler for when items are copied to the clipboard.  Here is a good starting point:

[How to use QClipboard.dataChanged signal to change the text in clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63259868/how-to-use-qclipboard-datachanged-signal-to-change-the-text-in-clipboard)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via the win32Clipboard library in python. First, we need to import it:

```
import win32clipboard
```

Next we have to open the clipboard and empty it:

```
win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
```

Now we'll put in your url:

```
url = win32clipboard.SetClipboardText('https://www.youtube.com/watch? 
v=dQw4w9WgXcQ')
```

Now we'll actually *get* the data:

```
data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
```

This is where the fun part comes in; we're going to check if the text placed is the one you want and then you run the script:

```
while True:
    if data == url:
        print('it happened!')
```

We can check it worked by copying the link.

This is the full code:

```
import win32clipboard
win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
url = win32clipboard.SetClipboardText('https://www.youtube.com/watch? 
v=dQw4w9WgXcQ')
data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
while True:
    if data == url:
        print('it happened!')
```